# Compare two words (full name) to an article text in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, web-scraping

Given a list of Full Names (First + Surname), how do your find the frequency that the names come up in a Text Article?

I am trying to find an efficient way of comparing the 'First Name' and 'Surname' of a person to a body of text. In this situation the body of text is a News Article and the names are of Australian Politicians.

The challenge is breaking up the news article into individual words, and then comparing the First Name && Last Name to words in the article. I have thought of turning the names into a JSON string but feel that would be inefficient and counter to learning an efficient way. I have been playing around with the enumerate function with no luck. The below function will work if the Surnames are removed from 'politicianName.txt', but will not work with the First Names and Surnames.

```
def getNames(articletext):
    politicianName  = open("politicianName.txt").read().split('\n')
    #for name in politicianName: #test the names read from file
    #    print name
    wordList = articletext.split()
    for word in wordList:
        if word in politicianName and word.isalnum():
            print word

article = 'Jacinta Allan this is an articletext scraped with urllib2'
getNames(article)



'''
#The enumerate example I have been testing and playing around with
mylist = [1, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3]
for i, j in enumerate(mylist[:-1]):
    if j  == mylist[i+1]: 
        mylist[i] = "foo" 
        mylist[i+1] = "foo"
print mylist
'''
```

politicianName.txt (in brief)

```
Jacinta Allan
Daniel Andrews
Neil Angus
Louise Asher
Brad Battin
```

Comment: frequency of name to words or frequency of names relative to one another?

Comment: The most efficient way depends on the relation of the amount of text to be searched in and the amount of names to be searched for. I would recommend iterating over the names, generating an regular-expression for each and count finditer()

Comment: Adding the First name only complicates things. A politician would never be mentioned without the Last name in the text. I cannot imagine reading "Jacinta passed a bill...". My point is, just search for the last name.

Comment: You need to add a sample of the articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
[x for x in politicianName if x in article and x is not'']
```

Input :

```
politicianName  = open("politicianName.txt").read().split('\n')
article = 'Jacinta Allan this is an articletext scraped with urllib2'
```

Out put :

```
['Jacinta Allan']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just splitting it altogether?

`politicianName = [v for i in open("politicianName.txt").read().split('\n') for v in i.split()]`

And then try the following

```
article = 'Jacinta Allan this is an articletext scraped with urllib2'
getNames(article)

article = 'Allan, Jacinta passed a bill'
getNames(article)
```

1st Output:
`Jacinta`
`Allan`
2nd Output:
`Jacinta`